# UIDatePicker background iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uidatepicker

For some reason the UIDatePicker on iOS 8 presents a white box in the background. After digging around for a bit, I cannot find an answer that solves the issue (see attached image).

Per other posts that describe a similar issue with iOS 7,  I have tried `UIAppearance` and looping through all of the UIDatePicker's subviews and changing the background to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Unfortunately, these have not resolved the issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: Have you added it as a sub-view to `UIActionSheet`? Are you testing on simulator? It may be a simulator only issue and the issue did not occur on device.

Comment: This is on both the device and simulator. It is not being placed as a subview of UIActionSheet. Works perfectly fine in iOS 7.

Comment: Publishing this with Xcode 5.1 versus Xcode 6.0.1 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "layer". Work on both iOS 7 and iOS 8. But this solution don't work with UIAppearance.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


.....
thePicker.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Any one has better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after looking for it I found this:

```
[[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIDatePicker class], nil] setBackgroundColor:nil]; // for iOS 8
```

I did this in the ViewController's viewDidLoad, where the UIDatePicker is set. This did the trick for me.

More explanations here: [UIDatePicker issues in popovers on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916124/uidatepicker-issues-in-popovers-on-ios-8)